# Inserting cart product to database after order placement with Crinsane Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Crinsane Laravel in my ecommerce project. I want to add the cart products as an order in the `order` table. I have used `foreach` function in the OrderController:

```
use App\Models\Order;

public function __construct(Order $order){
    $this->order = $order;
}

public function store(Request $request)
    {
        foreach(Cart::content() as $row){
            $data['product_id'] = $row->id;
            $data['price'] = $row->price;
            $data['quantity'] = $row->qty;
            $data['color_id'] = $row->options->color_id;
            $data['size_id'] = $row->options->size_id;
            $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $data['order_id'] = $request->order_id;
            $data['status'] = 'Processing';
            $this->order->fill($data);
            $this->order->save();
        }
        $notification = array(
            'alert-type' => 'success',
            'message' => 'Order submitted successfully.'
        );
        Cart::destroy();
        $order_id = $request->order_id;
        $order_detail = $this->order->with('products')->where('order_id', $order_id)->get();
        return view('frontend.cod.success',compact('order_detail','notification','order_id'));
     }
```

But the above code only saves one product data in the database. What is wrong going here?

**Edit**
The output of `dd(Cart::Content());`

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#463 ▼


#items: array:2 [▼
    "adc28c54b34a48fc6a61151579c914ba" => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem {#464 ▼
      +rowId: "adc28c54b34a48fc6a61151579c914ba"
      +id: 114
      +qty: 1
      +name: "Air Cushion Damping Boys Sneakers Soft Bottom  Sports Shoes 485"
      +price: 2000.0
      +options: Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions {#465 ▼
        #items: array:4 [▼
          "image" => "https://example.com/uploads/IMG_0939.png"
          "slug" => "air-cushion-damping-boys-sneakers-soft-bottom--sports-shoes-485"
          "color_id" => "5"
          "size_id" => "195"
        ]
      }
      -associatedModel: "App\Models\Product"
      -taxRate: 0
      -isSaved: false
    }
    "ed928a560633f9bab8a0d1ed5bb0ca20" => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem {#466 ▼
      +rowId: "ed928a560633f9bab8a0d1ed5bb0ca20"
      +id: 74
      +qty: 1
      +name: "ladies fashionable shoes"
      +price: 2000.0
      +options: Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions {#467 ▼
        #items: array:4 [▼
          "image" => "https://example.com/uploads/-31854440.jpg"
          "slug" => "ladies-fashionable-shoes"
          "color_id" => "5"
          "size_id" => "201"
        ]
      }
      -associatedModel: "App\Models\Product"
      -taxRate: 0
      -isSaved: false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with what is in ```dd(Cart::content());```

Comment: @KurtFriars There is two products on the cart when I do `dd(Cart::content());` but I don't know why the `foreach` is not working.

Comment: Please add the output to your question.

Comment: @KurtFriars I have added the output. Can you please check?

Comment: What is ```$this->order```?

Comment: @KurtFriars It is object of Order Model. I have updated my question.

Comment: I made an answer based on some assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
foreach(Cart::content() as $row){
    ...
    $this->order->fill($data);
    $this->order->save();
}
```

I am making some assumptions here, but It should look more like:

```
foreach (Cart::content() as $row){
    ...
    $order = new Order();
    $order->fill($data);
    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: I think `$product->fill()` save data on `products` table which I don't want. My code on the question is working but it is not looping to all the cart items in the cart. You can see there is 2 items in the cart but my code insert only one item in `orders` table.

Comment: In your code, you are filling the data into the same model.... I would guarantee you the data persisted, is the second item in the ```Cart::Content()``` array from your question.

Comment: A new product, or a new order? I will update my answer so you can accept it.

Comment: New order since I am adding data to `orders` table. You can update your answer.